# Get Call for JSON data, then looping through to find total values of a data point

Tags: javascript, json, loops, knockout.js

Goal is to make a get call and loop through the JSON data and find the total vehicles in service (true value) and out of service (false value).

JSON example (Single Array):

```
  [{
    TxId : "",
    Value : {
      Vin : "",
      Owner : "",
      VehicleType : "",
      LastLocation : "",
      InService : false
    },
    Timestamp : "",
    IsDelete : ""
  }, 
    TxId : "",
    Value : {
      Vin : "",
      Owner : "",
      VehicleType : "",
      LastLocation : "",
      InService : false
    },
    Timestamp : "",
    IsDelete : ""
  }, 
    TxId : "",
    Value : {
      Vin : "",
      Owner : "",
      VehicleType : "",
      LastLocation : "",
      InService : false
    },
    Timestamp : "",
    IsDelete : ""
  }]
```

I have started my js file code:

```
function barChartModel(context) {
         const self = this;

         /* chart data */
         let barSeries = [{name: "In-service", items: [0]},
                          {name: "Out-of-service", items: [0]}];

        $.get("http://localhost:9000/vehicles", (data) => {
```

How would I go about looping through this JSON data to find the totals of vehicles in service vs out of service. My goal is to use that data to create bar chart visualization. I am a little lost now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":false},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""},{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":false},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""},{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":false},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""}];


var inServiceCount = ko.utils.arrayFilter(data, function(item){
    return item.Value.InService;
}).length;

var outOfServiceCount = data.length - inServiceCount; // Assuming InService is boolean and can not be null

console.log(inServiceCount); //0
console.log(outOfServiceCount); //3
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn1vz2yp/)

Comment: `item.InService` should probably be `item.Value.InService`

Answer (score 0):

There's two points to you question:

1. The basic logic of counting a specific type of item in an array
2. Working with async data and (probably?) a chart rendering library in knockout

### 1. Getting the bar values

The other answer already showed an approach by using `filter`. I'd like to suggest an alternative using `reduce`:

```js
const data = [{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":false},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""},{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":false},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""},{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":true},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""}];

const inService = data.reduce(
  (sum, x) => sum + (x.Value.InService ? 1 : 0),
  0
);

console.log(inService);
```

## 2. Working with async data

You can use an observable array to write the data response to. Then, you can have a computed automatically recalculate the in-service sums when anything changes and combine it in to your chart data.

By subscribing to the computed chart data, you can trigger some sort of external update to rerender the graphs (depending on which library you use)

```js
const isInService = ({ Value: { InService }}) => InService;
const count = (pred, xs) => 
  xs.reduce((sum, x) => sum + pred(x), 0);

// App
// When the async call completes, it writes to this array
const data = ko.observableArray([]);

// Whenever the data changes, this outputs a new configuration
// object
const graphData = ko.computed(() => {
  const inService = count(isInService, data());
  return [
    { name: "In-service", items: [inService]},
    { name: "Out-of-service", items: [data().length - inService]}
  ];
});

// The first render renders an empty graph, the data hasn't
// yet loaded
renderGraph(graphData());

// Ensure future updates
graphData.subscribe(renderGraph);

// Load initial data
fakeFetch("/someUrl").then(data);


// Utils
function fakeFetch() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(
      res.bind(null, getData()), 
      1000
    )
  })
}

function renderGraph(graphData) {
  console.log(
    graphData.map(bar => 
      bar.name.padEnd(16, " ") + "|" +
      Array(bar.items[0]).fill("⬛").join("")
    ).join("\n")
  );
}

function getData() { return [{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":false},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""},{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":false},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""},{"TxId":"","Value":{"Vin":"","Owner":"","VehicleType":"","LastLocation":"","InService":true},"Timestamp":"","IsDelete":""}]; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```